# Ionic GET Object Index to ngFor

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the following JSON data. I was able to extract it on the js file, and was able to log via a console.log. However, I could not get the data to display correctly.

I tried to search on stackoverflow, however could not get the right option and would like to ask for help.

```
{
    "service": "weather",
    "daily": {
        "summary": "Light rain tomorrow and Friday.",
        "icon": "rain",
        "data": [
            {
                "time": 1581436800,
                "summary": "Humid and partly cloudy throughout the day."
            },
            {
                "time": 1581523200,
                "summary": "Light rain in the morning and afternoon."
            },
            {
                "time": 1581609600,
                "summary": "Possible drizzle in the morning."
            },
            {
                "time": 1581696000,
                "summary": "Humid and partly cloudy throughout the day."
            },
            {
                "time": 1581782400,
                "summary": "Humid throughout the day."
            },
            {
                "time": 1581868800,
                "summary": "Humid and partly cloudy throughout the day."
            },
            {
                "time": 1581955200,
                "summary": "Humid and partly cloudy throughout the day."
            },
            {
                "time": 1582041600,
                "summary": "Humid throughout the day."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With two files for the retrieval and display.

> weather.page.ts

```
constructor(private http: HTTP) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/weather', {}, {})
      .then(data => {

        const parsedBody = JSON.parse(data.data)
        this.dailyData = parsedBody.daily.data

        console.log("this.dailyData:");
        console.log(this.dailyData);

      })
      .catch(error => {
          // ...
      });
    }
```

> weather.page.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let data of dailyData">
 <ion-label>
    <h2>Tomorrow</h2>
    <p>{{data[0].summary}}</p>
 </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

> {{data[0].summary}}

Answer (score 0):

use async pipe in your *ngFor

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let data of dailyData |async ">
 <ion-label>
    <h2>Tomorrow</h2>
    <p>{{data[0].summary}}</p>
 </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I got this error. I might be missing something? ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {time: 1581436800, summary: "Humid and partly cloudy throughout the day.", icon: "partly-cloudy-day", sunriseTime: 1581458220, sunsetTime: 1581501060, …}
1: {time: 1581523200, summary: "Light rain in the morning and afternoon.", icon: "rain", sunriseTime: 1581544620, sunsetTime: 1581587460, …}
2: {time: 1581609600, summary: "Possible drizzle in the morning.", icon: "rain", sunriseTime: 1581631020, sunsetTime: 1581673920, …}

Comment: issue with your response handling

Comment: Yeah, trying to figure that out :/